# Removing sprite assigned as Child to another sprite - Phaser

Tags: javascript, sprite, phaser-framework

I have assigned a sprite as the child of another sprite. Basically, I'm trying to equip a Wizard with his Staff and have the staff follow him as he moves.

```
Melee.handleInput = function (wizard) {
    if (wizard.state !== STATE.STANDING) {
        var staff = new Melee(game, 0, 0);
        staff.scale.set(.60, .60);
        // Tweak anchor position to correctly align over player
        staff.anchor.setTo(.07, -0.4);
        wizard.addChild(staff);
        wizard.body.velocity.y = 600;
    }

};
```

However, I only want this to occur when the wizard's `state` is either `flying, falling, jumping or diving`, hence the `if` statement.

That all works well. When the down arrow is pressed, the staff appears and follows the wizard as it lands to the ground.

Now I want the staff to go away after the wizard lands. But I'm not sure how to access the staff sprite and kill it. Part of the problem may be that it has been assigned as a child of another sprite. How do I access the children of other sprites?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've never used Phaser, but the documentation for the [Phaser.Sprite](http://www.phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Sprite.html#children) object lists a number of properties and methods that you might use, e.g., children, getChildAt, getChildIndex. They also have a [forum](http://www.phaser.io/community/forum) where people might be better able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save a reference

```
wizard.staff = wizard.addChild(staff);
wizard.staff.kill()
```

But you can also access children directly

```
wizard.children.forEach(
  function(child){
    if(child instanceof Melee) child.kill();
  }
);
```